# Android: How to get latitude and longitude without GMS package

Tags: android, android-maps

How to get latitude and longitude without GMS package, I can use of mobile network for this but device d't have gms package.

Comment: its not duplicate, as you mentioned one using GMS package, I need without GMS package, thanks

Comment: My advise, read again the linked question answers (the scored 145 for instance)

Comment: i have update the code you can check it out below code.

Comment: After R&D I have came to know that Network Provider needs GMS package, where as GPS provider no need of GMS package